# Swift 3, throwing NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: swift, syntax, swift3

I have real simple code, but it throws a NSInvalidArgumentException, I wonder why?

My class is defined like this with a construtor

```
class mNoxGetDriverDetails : HTTPRestClient {

    private var demographicsPojo : DemographicsPojo

    init(phoneNumber: String, passcode :String) {   
    // init code 
    // super.init()
    }
```

I call the following in a `Test` and I get a `NSInvalidArgumentException` at here

```
let getDriverDetails : mNoxGetDriverDetails = mNoxGetDriverDetails(phoneNumber: "94644187512", passcode : "passcode")
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

**Edit** : More code

```
class mNoxGetDriverDetails : HTTPRestClient {
private var demographicsPojo : DemographicsPojo

    init(phoneNumber: String, passcode :String) {

        let demographicsPojoData : NSDictionary = [
            "isDemographicsActive":DemographicsPojoWrapper.IsDemographicsActive.YES,
            "demographicsRoleType" : DemographicsPojoWrapper.DemographicsRoleType.DRIVER,
            "mobilePhone":phoneNumber,
            "isTermsAndConditonsAccepted" : DemographicsPojoWrapper.IsTermsAndConditonsAccepted.YES]
        demographicsPojo = DemographicsPojo(dictionary: demographicsPojoData)!
        let demographicsPojoWrapperData : NSDictionary = ["demographicsPojo":demographicsPojo,
                                                          "isMinimalObject" : true,
                                                          "minimalWrapperObjectPurpose": AllTablesGlobals.AllWrappersObjectPurpose
                                                            .GET_SPECIFIC_RECORD_FROM_BACKEND]
        let demographicsPojoWrapper : DemographicsPojoWrapper = DemographicsPojoWrapper(dictionary: demographicsPojoWrapperData)!
        super.init(apiUrl: "Driver/getDriverDetails", operation: God.mNoxAPIs.mNoxGetDriverDetails, postData: demographicsPojoWrapper.dictionaryRepresentation())
    }
```

Comment: First you should use Capital letters for class (or in general: type) names. What's within the init code?

Comment: Can you provide full init() and class structure code?

Comment: NSInvalidArgumentException means that you called an invalid func signature to a class (in this case, 'mNoxGetDriverDetails'). I can't offer that as an answer, because I see nothing wrong with the code you've provided.

Comment: Provided the full init method. Please share some wisdom. Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to find out why? I have a section of code also bumping into similar error

Comment: On yeah, cant run network related stuff in tests if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my case,

to solve it by

**Add `-all_load` to the other linker flags in your build settings.**

> -all_load forces the linker to load all object files from every archive it sees, even those without Objective-C code.